# Objective-c: Difference between using properties via dot notation and methods?

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the difference between getting and setting properties via dot notation and via sending message?

```
... = anObject.property;
... = [anObject property];

anObject.property = ...;
[anObject setProperty:...];
```

Is the dot notation only a syntactic suger for message sending and the code is compiled exactly the same or there are some differences with `nil` handling, performance, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the dot notation only syntactic sugar for message sending and the code is compiled exactly the same?

Yes, they're exactly the same.